# Difference between Holographic and Red Dot sight?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In Call Of Duty Modern Warfare 2, what is the difference between the red dot sights and the holographic sights?

They both look almost the same except for with holographic sometimes I'll see a blue blur surrounding the red dot. What is the actual difference in them though and what makes holographic better?

Comment: Also see this related forum posting: http://www.gamespot.com/pc/action/modernwarfare2/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-52234606&pid=951942

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was sure this had been answered before but I couldn't find it...

The holographic provides a small amount of "Zoom" of the sight (not the rest of the world) in comparison to the Red Dot (obviously looking down either or just your "irons" provides some level of Zoom).  As a result the "dot" on the Holographic is slightly larger and covers more of your vision.  By comparison, the surroundings of the Red Dot are "smaller" and thus occlude less of a crucial part of your screen.
[image]

Personally I always prefer the Red Dot.

Comment: Ok one more question. Why can I see like a blueish glow with the holographic but not the red dot? It appears to only show whenever enemies are near though.

Comment: @Earlz do you have a screenshot? I can't reproduce

Comment: I'll attempt to get something later today. That is what I thought the difference was between the two was something with that blueish blur. Also I'm on XBox 360.

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out but it doesn't make sense to me. It apparently reflects light from behind you. So if there is a light behind you and you look down the sight you'll see a very distorted image of what's behind you, this is the "blue blur" I was talking about. It only occurs when you are in front of a light though and have your back to the light.

Answer (score 2):

Some guns actually make a difference between the two. For instance the M-16 is horribly inaccurate with a red-dot site, but for some reason, intentional or not, it becomes significantly more accurate with a holographic site.

(stand at one side of a room and shoot at the same spot with both sites, you'll notice the spread almost instantly)

My experience has been, more accurate players are often better with the red dot, due to the precision and smaller sight.  The holographic however, is often easier for less accurate players due to the larger 'sweet spot'