# What's the difference between the Red Dot and Reflex sights?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

What's the difference between the Red Dot and Reflex sights in Call of Duty: Black Ops?

Comment: I was *so* ready to find a duplicate on this, but [it's both a different game *and* a different pair of sights](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/difference-between-holographic-and-red-dot-sight "Although it still was a Red Dot, haha~"). Well, hopefully this comment will stop others from engaging in their own similarly futile searches.

Comment: it sounds like you manage your time well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from [COD Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Reflex_Sight):

> The differences between the Reflex Sight and the Red Dot Sight is the Reflex Sight has a slightly larger field of view when looking through the optics.

Personally, I am a bit more comfortable with the reflex sight than with the RDS.
Tactically, there is almost no difference.

Comment: lets not forget you can customize your reflex dot to whatever you like. My personal fav is the cyan coloured X.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Reflex Sights produces more "tunnel vision" compared to Red Dot Sights, which reduces your field of vision slightly when aiming down the sight. But as for gameplay mechanics-wise, they function pretty much the same.