# What's the difference between the "Red Dot Sight"  and "Holographic Sight" attachments?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

The question has been asked for Modern Warfare 2.

[Difference between Holographic and Red Dot sight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/difference-between-holographic-and-red-dot-sight)

Does it function the same for Modern Warfare 3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the exact same as in Modern Warfare 2.  A holographic provides slightly more zoom as well as a bigger target area.